# How to measure sequential and parallel runtimes of Haskell program

Tags: haskell, runtime, parallel-processing, measurement

I am taking measurement of the haskell program from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798996/multicore-programming-in-haskell-control-parallel) to produce the following table with runtimes and speedups summary so I can plot in a graph.

```
#Cores     Runtimes       Speedups
                     Absolute  Relative
Seq        ?         ..        ..
1          3.712     ..        ..
2          1.646     ..        ..
```

**First question**

While the runtimes on 1 and 2 cores are taken by compiling the program with the `-threaded` flag on ([3] and [4] below), I am not sure which time to take for the sequential one ([1] or [2] below):

- should it be the time obtained by compiling without the `-threaded` flag, or
- that obtained with the flag on but then NOT specifying any number of cores i.e. with no `-Nx`

**Compiling without `-threaded` flag**

```
        $ ghc --make -O2 test.hs
    [1] $ time ./test           ## number of core = 1
        102334155

        real    0m4.194s
        user    0m0.015s
        sys     0m0.046s
```

**Compiling with `-threaded` flag**

```
        $ ghc --make -O2 test.hs -threaded -rtsopts
    [2] $ time ./test           ## number of core = not sure?
        102334155

        real    0m3.547s
        user    0m0.000s
        sys     0m0.078s

    [3] $ time ./test +RTS -N1  ## number of core = 1
        102334155

        real    0m3.712s
        user    0m0.016s
        sys     0m0.046s

    [4] $ time ./test +RTS -N2  ## number of core = 2
        102334155

        real    0m1.646s
        user    0m0.016s
        sys     0m0.046s
```

**Second question**

As can be seen from above, I am using the `time` command to measure the runtimes. I am taking the 'real' time. But if I run the program with the `-sstderr` flag on, I get more detailed information:

```
    $ ghc --make -O2 test.hs -rtsopts
    $ ./test +RTS -sstderr 
    102334155
             862,804 bytes allocated in the heap
               2,432 bytes copied during GC
              26,204 bytes maximum residency (1 sample(s))
              19,716 bytes maximum slop
                   1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

      Generation 0:     1 collections,     0 parallel,  0.00s,  0.00s elapsed
      Generation 1:     1 collections,     0 parallel,  0.00s,  0.00s elapsed

      INIT  time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
      MUT   time    3.57s  (  3.62s elapsed)
      GC    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
      EXIT  time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
      Total time    3.57s  (  3.62s elapsed)

      %GC time       0.0%  (0.0% elapsed)

      Alloc rate    241,517 bytes per MUT second

      Productivity 100.0% of total user, 98.6% of total elapsed
```

I believe that the `-sstderr` provides a more accurate time which I should use instead of the `time` command. Am I correct? Also, which of the 'Total time' (3.57s or 3.62s) should I use?

And finally, any general advice/good practice while taking measurements like this? I am aware that there are some packages that allow us to benchmark our program, but I am mainly interested in taking the measurements manually (or using a script to do that for me).

Also: the runtimes are the median of running the program 3 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `-N1` for the single-core time.  I believe that also constrains the GC to use one core (which seems fitting for the benchmark, I think?), but others may know more.

As for your second question, the answer to benchmarking in Haskell is nearly always to use [criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion/).  Criterion will allow you to time one run of the program, and you can then wrap it in a script which runs the program with `-N1`, `-N2`, etc.  Taking the median of 3 runs is okay as a very quick and rough indicator, but if you want to rely on the results then you'll need a lot more runs than that.  Criterion runs your code enough and performs the appropriate statistics to give you a sensible average time, as well as confidence intervals and standard deviation (and it tries to correct for how busy your machine is).  I know you asked about best practice for doing it yourself, but Criterion already embodies a lot of it: use clock time, benchmark a lot, and as you realised, don't just take a simple mean of the results.

Criterion requires very little change to your program if you want to benchmark the whole thing.  Add this:

```
import Criterion.Main

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain [bench "My program" oldMain]
```

where `oldMain` is whatever your main function used to be.

Comment: I hope you realise that there is a difference between the sequential time and the time it takes on one core (obtained by using the flag `-N1` with `-threaded` on). I need both absolute (sequential time / parallel time on n cores) and relative (parallel time on 1 core / parallel time on n cores) speedups. My question is about which time to take for the sequential run? Should it be by compiling the code with/without `-threaded`?

Comment: If we don't use `-threaded` we cannot use `-Nx`, but if we do, we can leave out `-Nx`. I wonder if the program then runs on all cores or defaults to sequential (which I doubt a bit as we have compiled with `-threaded` flag).

Comment: With -threaded and without -Nx, GHC defaults to a "sensible" value of -Nx. IIRC, the sensible value here is the number of cores minus one; though sensibilities may have changed when I wasn't looking.

Comment: makes sense to me. anyone could confirm this and that it has not changed?

Comment: ok,on a dual core machine, if i compile without `-threaded` and print `numCapabilities`, output is 1 (obviously). With `-threaded` flag on and not specifying `-Nx`, output is 1 (interesting. so ghc seems to interpret it as `-N1`). When I specify `-Nx`, output is `x`. Now this behaviour may not be the same on machines with higher number of cores...